# specify location in wsdl:import

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I'm trying to have my WCF services run completely off HTTPS. However when WCF generates the WSDL it provides locations that are not secure (http) and not allowed (rejected) by server.

How do i get this:

```
<wsdl:import namespace="https://www.mydomain.com/ogc/csw/ebrim/wsdl1.1" location="http://www.mydomain.com/ogc/csw?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
```

to read this (notice location attribute now using https):

```
<wsdl:import namespace="https://www.mydomain.com/ogc/csw/ebrim/wsdl1.1" location="https://www.mydomain.com/ogc/csw?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
```

I can specify my namespace in my interface file but i don't' see how to specify location.:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "https://www.mydomain.com/ogc/csw/ebrim/wsdl1.1", ConfigurationName = "MyDomain")]
public interface ICatalog
{
```

I've tried modifying my baseAddress, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the httpsGetEnabled configuration property on the wcf stack. Check the following link to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733114%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)